# How to bind events to the rendition in epub.js

Tags: javascript, epub.js

I want to register a right click listener on the page in `epub.js` but don't know how to do it. There is also `passEvents` method of rendition object but couldn't find any help on that either. This is my last try:

```
rendition.on("rendered", () => {
    const contents = rendition.getContents()
    contents.document.addEventListener('contextmenu', showContextMenu, false);
});
```

Comment: Do you want to pass the event when `rendition` is rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you asked and I hope I got it right, you want a `contextmenu` event at the book itself, right?

If that's the case I used the following JS:

```
rendition.on("rendered", (e,i) => {;
  i.document.documentElement.addEventListener('contextmenu', (cfiRange, contents) => {
      console.log('hey');
  })
});
```

This code simply returns `hey` when I right click *at* the book. But as you can see there are two parameters `(cfiRange, contents)` which contains what you need.

In any case, I created a [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/25ecmjpk/1/)

Another solution would be use `document` as the element receiving the event, but in my tests it gets everything *but* the book.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer applies to `"epubjs": "^0.3.88` which I'm using on a project where I want to completely disable user right click or user long press on every device.

When rendition is rendered, we get two parameters one of them being an `iframe`. If you inspect your reader you'll notice your epub file is being rendered inside an iframe. That's why adding the event listener to the main document of your application does not work.

After this you attach a `contextmenu` event to the iframe. This callback will return an event `MouseEvent` which you can cancel with `event.preventDefault();`. Then you could access the event rect properties to render anything in the location the user right-clicked. For this you could for example use `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`.

```
rendition.on('rendered', (rendition: Rendition, iframe: Window) => {
    helpers.log('Rendition rendered');
    iframe.document.documentElement.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event: MouseEvent) => {
        helpers.log('Stopping contextual menu coming from epubjs iframe');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps to anyone working with `epubjs` in 2021.